# Why am I getting this on sqlfiddle.com?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlfiddle

[image: SQL Fiddle screenshot]

I am a beginner in SQL, and started using this website sqlfiddle.com for practicing. I successfully build schema, but when I try to execute sql queries,sometimes it executes and sometimes i get this error : Oops something went wrong. Try it again and if it keeps happening email admin@sqlfiddle.com. Is there something wrong in my input or this is the problem of the website.

Comment: Remove last table, try again. Did it work? If YES, put it back, but with last part removed, start over. If NO. Put it back, remove second last table, start over.

Comment: You should simply file a bug report and send them your script and browser and OS info. Their About section says their email address is admin<at>sqlfiddle<dot>com.

Comment: If you want to practice, you better install an rdbms (even ms access or sqlite will do) on your computer and use that. This way you will not rely on the sqlfiddle.com being reachable and working.

Comment: It's also worth noting that certain options won't be usable in SQLFiddle because of timeout issues. This is especially true when you make wasteful queries.